How to debug a @for loop issue in Angular 17?
CONTEXT:
Angular 17 App connected to ExpressJS app in the backend.
Angular app components:

card-item
list-items
others Not Relevant

Services:
categories:
export class CategoriesService {

    private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api/categories';

    private httpClient = inject(HttpClient);

    async getAll() {
        return firstValueFrom(
            this.httpClient.get<Category[]>(this.baseUrl)
        );
    }

    getByCategoryTitle(categoryTitle: string) {
        return firstValueFrom(this.httpClient.get<Category[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/${categoryTitle}`));
    }

}

items:
export class ItemsService {

    private baseUrl = `${environment.apiUrl}/items`;

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

    async getAll() {
        return firstValueFrom(
            this.httpClient.get<Item[]>(this.baseUrl)
        );
    }

}

Interfaces:
categories:
export interface Item {
    id: number;
    organization: string;
    title: string;
    stDate: string;
    endDate: string;
    description: string;
    categoryTitle: string;
    categoryId: number;
}


items:
export interface Category {
    categoryId: number;
    categoryTitle: string;
}

Components
Card-item (TS):
export class CardItemComponent {

  @Input() item: Item | null = null;

  itemsService = inject(ItemsService);

}

Card-item (HTML):
@if (item) {
<div class="item">
    <p class="title" id="org">Organization: <span>{{item.organization}}</span></p>
    <p class="title" id="title">Project: <span>{{item.title}}</span></p>
    <p class="title" id="st-date">Start date: <span>{{item.stDate}}</span></p>
    <p class="title" id="end-date">End date: <span>{{item.endDate}}</span></p>
    <p class="title" id="description">Description: <span>{{item.description}}</span>
    </p>
    <hr>
</div>
}

List-item(TS):
export class ListItemsComponent {
  router = inject(Router);

  //----------- DATA-----------//
  categories: Category[] = [];
  allCategories: Item[] = [];
  itemsByCategory: { [categoryTitle: string]: Item[] } = {};
  arrItems: Item[] = [];
  category: Item | null = null;
  item: Item | null = null;


  //----------- SERVICES-----------//
  categoriesService = inject(CategoriesService);
  itemsService = inject(ItemsService);
  Object: any;


  //----------- NG-ON-INIT -----------//
  async ngOnInit() {

    // ALL CATEGORIES
    this.allCategories = await this.itemsService.getAll();

    // ALL ITEMS
    this.arrItems = await this.itemsService.getAll();

    // CATEGORIES WITH ITEMS
    this.arrItems.forEach(item => {
      const categoryTitle = item.categoryTitle;
      if (!this.itemsByCategory[categoryTitle]) {
        this.itemsByCategory[categoryTitle] = [];
      }
      this.itemsByCategory[categoryTitle].push(item);
    });
  }
}

List-item (HTML):
<section>
    <div>
        @for (item of arrItems; track $index) {
        <h2>{{ item.categoryTitle }}</h2>

        <div>
            @for (item of arrItems; track $index) {
            <div>
                <card-item [item]="item"></card-item>
            </div>
            }
        </div>
        }
    </div>
</section>

I am able to see using the console log the objects in the LIST OF ITEMS as I need them, meaning that the Category Title is shown once per category, and all the items (with their features) in the category are shown underneath the category title:
Object { Projects: (5) […], Experience: (3) […], Education: (3) […], Certifications: (2) […] }
​
Certifications: Array [ {…}, {…} ]
​​
0: Object { _id: "66339fa38eaadfa13595bc5b", categoryId: 4, categoryTitle: "Certifications", … }
​​
1: Object { _id: "66339fa38eaadfa13595bc5c", categoryId: 4, categoryTitle: "Certifications", … }
​​
length: 2
​​
<prototype>: Array []
​
Education: Array(3) [ {…}, {…}, {…} ]
​
Experience: Array(3) [ {…}, {…}, {…} ]
​
Projects: Array(5) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]

With the current HTML @for what happens is that I see the category titles (and items) as many times as there are items. I need to show the category title once, and each item within the category to be shown just once, not repeated times as now.
For example:
Certifications:

AWS....
Google Cloud...
Oracle...

REPOSITORIES
Front-End:
https://github.com/cativi/portfolio-frontend/tree/develop
Back-End:
https://github.com/cativi/portfolio_backend/tree/develop

@user24890162 please share github repo link!

https://github.com/cativi/portfolio-frontend/tree/develop

@NarenMurali: if you find yourself needing a public repo (or an external code runner) to understand the question, the ideal course of action is to vote to close the question. Questions that need external links are considered to be missing a [mcve].

When answering questions, do please help question authors ask a good question, rather than just answering anything. It is sometimes better to be judicious as to what is answered here, so that we do not attract low-quality questions. This one wasn't too bad, but the author did not know that we do not like vague titles. That is something you should know, and if you can edit the question to fix that, so much the better.

Curators sometimes give this advice: Questions that ask "please help me" tend to be looking for highly localized guidance, or in some cases, ongoing or private assistance, which is not suited to our Q&A format. It is also rather vague, and is better replaced with a more specific question. Please read Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?.

I have edited the title a little, but perhaps you (or the OP) could improve it further.

It's better to use plain observables instead of promises to keep your code simple.
Note how, in the below code, I moved all the code inside the subscribe. The reason is because the code below the subscribe will not wait for the subscribe to complete, so we need to move the code inside the subscribe.
In the service, I just converted the API call to the simple http get request, that returns an observable:
getAll() {
    return this.httpClient.get<Item[]>(this.baseUrl);
}

In the component, we subscribe to the getAll() and set the required properties inside the subscribe block:
...
ngOnInit() {
    // ALL ITEMS
    this.itemsService.getAll().subscribe((res: Item[]) => {
      this.arrItems = res;
      this.allCategories = res;


    // CATEGORIES WITH ITEMS
    this.arrItems.forEach(item => {
      const categoryTitle = item.categoryTitle;
      if (!this.itemsByCategory[categoryTitle]) {
        this.itemsByCategory[categoryTitle] = [];
      }
      this.itemsByCategory[categoryTitle].push(item);
    });
    ...

Forked Github Repo

Hi Naren, thanks for taking the time to reply my help request. I have done the changes that you suggested to the code, but the issue persists. Maybe I didn't explain it properly.  Basically I want to show the category title once per category, and within each category show all the items which have that category. Items at the same time have various features: title, description, etc. Thanks again!

@ctv please share the data from the API and update on the question, it will help to debug!

I've added the repositories to the question. Thanks! @naren-murali
